# Get Weather forecast detail from current location

Tags: iphone, weather-api

In my app i was using google api to get weather details, but i just know that it's no more working.

Yahoo weather API good to use but it's not for commercial use as per its terms so i can't use it.

Can anyone please suggest any way or provide any link to use other weather API.

Thanks.

Comment: If only this had been asked many MANY times before and there was some way of SEARCHING those questions to find the answers.....

Comment: What weather details are you looking for? RSSWeather.com's US forecasts are [in public domain](http://www.rssweather.com/dir) and in XML.

Comment: @hd1 I am looking for forecast detail, max-min temperature and weather condition as per user's current location in my app.

Comment: See my answer in that case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two links which giving weather reports

http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather.aspx and 
                                                                             http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/

Note : In both there is also limitation for the number of request per day and per hour

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get [US Weather in RSS](http://www.rssweather.com) here. For the UK, the [BBC provides this service, also in RSS](http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/w2/3dayforecast.rss) -- postal code W2 is given as an example. These are also public domain. I can find other countries, just leave a comment saying which you'd like.

Comment: thanks for answer but i want generalize (location can be any) not for specific country.

Comment: @OKNC2 I don't think you'll find it for anywhere on Earth, best you'll do is find country/region specific sites providing RSS.